# Set key equivalent to button programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard

I want to set a key equivalent to a button in my app.

My code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"D"];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"It worked!");
}
```

When I press `D` on the keyboard it doesn't do anything.
That's weird, because when I set the key equivalent in the xib it does work.
Does anyone know what to do to make it work?

Comment: Does the button work when you click? Did you type D of d?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, the button works when you click it.

Comment: Does it work when you set the key equivalent in the xib? Is myButton nil?

Comment: @Willeke myButton isn't nil. And yes, when I set the key equivalent in the xib it does work.

Comment: Do you want the key equivalent to be just the D key, or do you want the key equivalent to be ⌘D?

Comment: @Willeke You just press the D key, not ⌘D. So I think it's d (not D) then. Does that matter?

Comment: If I set the key equivalent to D (type d) in the xib, d works. If I set the key equivalent to D in code only D works. If I set the key equivalent to d in code only d works. So yes, the Shift key does matter.

Comment: @Willeke It does, it works now. Thank you. If you want credits you can answer the question (Answer: d instead of D). I'll mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in 'd' instead of 'D'.

```
[myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"d"];
```